# A recommendation for how to specify parameter values in C

Tags: c, simulation

I want to code a computer simulation in C. I am very new to C, have experience mostly in Python
and a little in Javascript. I want some suggestion about the best practice for the following.

The computer simulation is based on many parameters. What is the best way to specify the value of these parameters? Should they be specified as variables, or should I set their value using `#define` macro.

For example, I can do

```
int numpeople = 100;
```

or,

```
#define numpeople 100
```

Which is better practice, or does it not matter? The length of certain arrays in the simulation depends on parameters. If I specify parameter values
using the variable approach then I cannot use it to specify length array.

For example,

```
// This is invalid.
int numpeople = 10;
int ids[numpeople];
```

In this case, would you say that I do not have any choice and I should use

```
#define numpeople 100
int ids[numpeople];
```

or is there another better approach.

Finally, whichever way I define the parameters, I would like to list the possible values of the parameters in one place and then let the simulation run for each possible value. That is, suppose 
`parameter1` can take values 100, 200, 300 and `parameter2` can take value 5, 25, 50.

I want to first run the simulation where `parameter1` takes value 100, and `parameter2` takes value 5. Then, I want to run it with `parameter1` takes value 100, and `parameter2` takes value 25... and so on for all 9 combinations that can be formed with these values. I would prefer if I do not have to go manually and change the combination every time a simulation completes. Is there a way I could list all the combinations in some form (I am asking for a recommendation for data structure to use for this combination) and then have the code read one at a time. That is how would I set the value of the parameter during the run time.

There is perhaps no one way of doing this. But I would appreciate any way of doing this that you think is a good way.

Please let me know if you need any further clarification.

Thanks for reading this and for your answer.

Comment: `int numpeople = 10; int ids [numpeople];` is perfectly valid under C99 and C11.

Comment: The Google C++ style guide recommends against using macros for const values, it includes a list of [good reasons](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Preprocessor_Macros), click on the arrow on the left to show them.

Comment: @verbose I get the error `error: variably modified ‘ids’ at file scope` even when I specify -std=c99 in the gcc command. Is there something else I should be doing.
@Douglas thanks for the link about macros.

Comment: Ah yes, you can't do that at file scope. The size of a variable-length has to be known at runtime so the appropriate amount of memory can be allocated for it.  Since anything in the file could modify `numpeople`, it means that the size of `ids[]` cannot be known even at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

If your simulation is parameterized by many values, consider passing those in as a single struct to the setup of your simulation.  Like so:

```
struct Params {
  int num_people;
  int simulation_steps;
  int step_size;
  // ...
}

void your_simulation(const &Params params) {
  int people_ids[params.num_people];
  // ...
}
```

That way you can set up multiple runs in headers, or main files, or whatever.

```
Params small_sim = {
  .num_people = 10,
  .simulation_steps = 5,
  .step_size = 30,
};

Params big_sim = {
  .num_people = 100,
  .simulation_steps = 5000,
  .step_size = 3,
};

main() {

  if (...) {
    your_simulation(&small_sim);
  } else {
    your_simulation(&big_sim);
  }
}
```

This will make unit testing easier because you can set up fixed simulations with known expected output, also you can later expand the program to take in its parameters from input files, or the command line, or somewhere else.

Comment: I'm not up to C11 (or even C99). Is `const &Params params` valid ? I would think not.

Comment: A constant reference to a structure is just fine.  Should have been spelled "const Params &params" though.  I don't expect anyone will be cutting and pasting this code so I'm not worried.  Thanks for the comment though.

Comment: But does reference syntax exist in C11 ? I don't remember having read that anywhere.

Comment: References are fine in languages that support them. C does not.

Comment: If the questioner is using C only, then they will use pointers.  Different implementation of the same answer--pass in structs containing your parameters.  Anyone should feel free to edit the answer to satisfy needs for precision.

Comment: @caskey Thank you. I will check this. One thing is not clear, however. At a time I would prefer to run the simulation for about 100 different parameter combinations. You have listed `small_sim`, `big_sim` etc. Do I have to list 100 structs like that. What if values of only 2 or 3 parameters is changing across these simulations and those of, say 10 others, is constant. It appears that in your solution I will have to (1) list 100 structs, (2) repeat the values of the constant ones across 100 structs, and (3) do an if/else if statement with about 100 else ifs. Have I misunderstood your solution?

Comment: If you have many, many combinations of parameters then you would use an array of structs to make it easy to loop through them.  I assumed you would be choosing one of the sets for each run.

Comment: @caskey Thanks. This could work great. Could you (or anyone else) please let me know if the following is possible: (1) Could structs be specified so that variable that do not change need not be repeated for each member in the array, or is this not possible; (2) Can I create this array of structs programmatically using C (I can probably use Python to do it, but want to know if I can do it in C), or do I have to type them out. Would appreciate an example if the latter is possible.

Comment: Yes, structs are assignable to each other (it does a field-wise copy of values) so you could instead create a set of defaults, assign those to the struct variable then change what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass the parameter values as command line arguments to your programs.

for e.g.,

Comment: ./program_name <param1> <param2>